# Getting attribute error when sending data from one class to another

Tags: python, tkinter

I've created two different scripts, one to collect the data and another to save save it. I'm using tkinter to display a GUI for a user, the save button collects and displays the data, while also activating a method in another file. I've tried following along with some example, but I'm sure sure what went wrong. Error message is AttributeError: 'AdGUI' object has no attribute 'cust_name'. All help is appreciated. Code is as follows:

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import *
import customer


class AdGUI:
    def __init__(self):

        #create the main window widget
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.main_window.geometry('700x400')
        self.main_window.title('Acme Advertising')

        #create four frames
        self.pic_frame= tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.pic_frame.pack()
        self.name_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.name_frame.pack()
        self.email_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.email_frame.pack()
        self.data_frame= tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.data_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame.pack()
        

##        #create the picture
##
##        photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file ='acme.png')
##        self.image_label = tkinter.Label(self.pic_frame, image = photo)
##        self.image_label.pack()


        #create the widgets for the name frame
        self.name_label = tkinter.Label(self.name_frame, text = "Enter your name:  ", padx = 30, font='Helvetic 12 bold italic')
        self.name_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.name_frame, relief = 'ridge')
        self.name_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.name_entry.pack()

        #create the widgets for the email frame
        self.email_label = tkinter.Label(self.email_frame, text = "Enter your email address:  ", width=30, pady=10, font='Helvetic 12 bold italic')
        self.email_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.email_frame, width=30, relief='ridge', font='Arial 12 bold italic')
        self.email_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.email_entry.pack(side = 'right')

        #create the widgets fro the data collection 
        self.type_label = tkinter.Label(self.data_frame, text = "What type \n of pet do you have?")
        self.type_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.type_list = tkinter.Listbox(self.data_frame, height = 5, exportselection = 0)
        self.type_list.insert(1, 'Cat')
        self.type_list.insert(2, 'Dog')
        self.type_list.insert(3, 'Horse')
        self.type_list.insert(4, 'Fish')
        self.type_list.insert(5, 'Other')
        self.type_list.pack(side = 'left')

        
        self.age_label = tkinter.Label(self.data_frame, text = "Please select your \n age range.")
        self.age_label.pack(side = 'left')
        self.age_list = tkinter.Listbox(self.data_frame, height = 5, exportselection = 0)
        self.age_list.insert(1, '18-25')
        self.age_list.insert(2, '26-35')
        self.age_list.insert(3, '36-45')
        self.age_list.insert(4, '46-60')
        self.age_list.insert(5, 'Older than 60')
        self.age_list.pack(side = 'right')

        
        #create buttons
        self.save_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = 'See your savings!', command = self.save_data)
        self.save_button.pack(side = 'left')
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text = 'Exit', command = self.quit_program)
        self.quit_button.pack(side = 'right')
  
        #start the main loop, runs like an infinite loop until window is closed
        tkinter.mainloop()


    def quit_program(self):
        exit()

    def save_data(self):
        discount = ()
        store = ()
        cust_name = ()
        cust_email = ()
        
        self.pet = self.type_list.get(self.type_list.curselection())

        if self.pet == 'Cat':
            store = 'Bertha\'s Kitty Boutique'
        if self.pet == 'Dog':
            store = 'K9 Supplies'
        if self.pet == 'Horse':
            store = 'Saddle and Tack Shoppe'
        if self.pet == 'Fish':
            store = 'Aquariums & Stuff'
        if self.pet == 'Other':
            store = 'Pets-R-Us'


        self.discount = self.age_list.get(self.age_list.curselection())
        
        if self.discount == '18-25':
            discount = '20%'
        if self.discount == '26-35':
            discount = '15%'
        if self.discount == '36-45':
            discount = '10%'
        if self.discount == '46-60':
            discount = '5%'
        if self.discount == 'Older than 60':
            discount = '25%'


        cust_name = self.name_entry.get()
        cust_email = self.email_entry.get()
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('Discounts brought to you by Acme Advertising', f'{cust_name}, you\'re eligible for a {discount} discount at {store}.')

        #create an instance
        data = ''
        data = customer.customer(self.cust_name, self.cust_email, self.store, self.pet)

        data.save_text(self.cust_name, self.cust_email, self.store, self.pet)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Ad = AdGUI()
```

This is the code for the other file.

```
#filename  customer.py

class customer:
    def __init__(self, cust_name, cust_email, store, pet):
        self.__cust_name = cust_name
        self.__cust_email = cust_email
        self.__store = store
        self.__pet = pet
        
    def save_text(self, cust_name, cust_email, store, pet):
        with open('customerData.txt', 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(cust_name + '\n')
            outfile.write(cust_email + '\n')
            outfile.write(store + '\n')
            outfile.write(pet + '\n')
```

Comment: Your class doesn't have a cust_name attribute, it's just a local variable. Therefore `self.cust_name` should just be `cust_name`.

Comment: In the save_data method or save_text method?

Comment: Inside `save_data`

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble formatting it. I removed the self from the cust_name and cust_email. Code looks like this now.                       
`#create an instance
        data = ''
        data = customer.customer(cust_name, cust_email, self.store, self.pet)

        data.save_text(cust_name, cust_email, self.store, self.pet) `

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

Once you define variables in your init function, you can use them in that class. Try changing your class 'customer' so that it looks like this:

```
class Customer:
    def __init__(self, cust_name, cust_email, store, pet):
        self.cust_name = cust_name
        self.cust_email = cust_email
        self.store = store
        self.pet = pet
    
    def save_text(self):
        with open('customerData.txt', 'a') as outfile:
            outfile.write(self.cust_name + '\n')
            outfile.write(self.cust_email + '\n')
            outfile.write(self.store + '\n')
            outfile.write(self.pet + '\n')
```

---

Then, instead of having this in the save_data function of your class 'AdGUI':

```
data = ''
data = customer.Customer(self.cust_name, 
                         self.cust_email, 
                         self.store, 
                         self.pet)

data.save_text(self.cust_name, self.cust_email, self.store, self.pet)
```

Try this instead:

```
data = customer.customer(cust_name, 
                         cust_email, 
                         store, 
                         self.pet)
data.save_text()
```

In the save_data function, you define the variables self.pet, store, discount, cust_name and cust_email. You should use these when calling the class 'customer'.

It might be easier to change 'self.pet' to simply 'pet'. The prefix 'self.' is used when you want to use the variable 'pet' outside of the 'save_data' function.

---

---

**More tips**

Here are some best practice tips you might want to consider:

1. All of your class names should be capitalized

For example, your class 'customer' should be called 'Customer'.

2. Try importing tkinter like this: 'import tkinter as tk'

This just saves you some work later when you call Tkinter objects like a root or a frame:

```
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root)
```

3. Instead of importing your file 'customer', try importing the class 'Customer' from the file 'customer' like this:

   from customer import Customer

When calling the class 'Customer' in your save_data function, you can then define data as:

```
data = Customer(cust_name, 
                cust_email, 
                store, 
                self.pet)
```